# React Onclick events for button

Tags: reactjs, button, events, rxjs, onclick

**Hello, im trying to create buttons for functions to call every function.
when the user will click the button will call the function and that will show to the user the relevant output
I'm new in react and I'm trying to find a solution to this problem.**

```
class Counter extends Component{
state = {
studentArr: [
        {name:"name1",is_teacher: true, nick_name: "SupremeShushan", age: 31},
        {name:"name2",is_teacher: false, nick_name: "dd", age: 87},
        {name:"name3",is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Bing", age: 44},
        {name:"name4",is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Chains", age: 27},
        {name:"name5",is_teacher: true, nick_name: "Jp", age: 58},
        {name:"name6",is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Unix", age: 50},
        {name:"name7",is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Grouch", age: 33}]
};
     converBool(val){ // convert is_Teacher (boolean) and check if true or false and return value
     return (val === true) ? "yes" : "no";
 };

 render1 = () =>{ // return all the studentArr
    return (this.state.studentArr === 0) ? <p>No Students / Teachers Found!</p> :
    <ul><div><p>asdada</p></div>{this.state.studentArr.map(student => <li key={student.name}>Name: {student.name} ,Teacher: {this.converBool(student.is_teacher)} , NickName: {student.nick_name} , Age: {student.age}</li>)}</ul>
};

 render2 = () =>{
    let Teachers = this.state.studentArr.filter(t => t.is_teacher);
    return <ul><div><p>asdada</p></div>{Teachers.map(student => <li key={student.age}>Name: {student.name} ,Teacher: {this.converBool(student.is_teacher)} , NickName: {student.nick_name} , Age: {student.age}</li>)}</ul>
 };

 render3 = () =>{
    let Age = this.state.studentArr.filter(t => (t.age >= 50));
    return <ul><div><p>asdada</p></div>{Age.map(student => <li key={student.age}>Name: {student.name} ,Teacher: {this.converBool(student.is_teacher)} , NickName: {student.nick_name} , Age: {student.age}</li>)}</ul>
 };

 render4 = () =>{
    let NoneTeacherAge = this.state.studentArr.filter(t => (t.age < 30) && this.converBool(t.is_teacher));
    return <ul><div><p>asdada</p></div>{NoneTeacherAge.map(student => <li key={student.age} >Name: {student.name} ,Teacher: {this.converBool(student.is_teacher)} , NickName: {student.nick_name} , Age: {student.age}</li>)}</ul>
 };
 render() 
 {
    return <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.render1}>
            Click To See All Teachers
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={this.render2}>
            Click To See All Teachers
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={this.render3}>
            Click To See All Age 50+
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={this.render4}>
            Click To See All Student with Age below 30
        </button>

    </React.Fragment>;
 }
```

}

export default Counter;

**When I run the program it shows me the buttons but when I press it does not call any function and shows nothing!**

Comment: Can you tell us which is "this problem"?

Comment: the main render(){
the button dosent show any thing
}

Comment: You need to store the result of invoke render1..4 in component state, and render it according to selected option

Comment: @lissettdm how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property in component state to manage the selected option (1..4), and one render function:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: null,
    studentArr: [
      { name: "name1", is_teacher: true, nick_name: "SupremeShushan", age: 31 },
      { name: "name2", is_teacher: false, nick_name: "dd", age: 87 },
      { name: "name3", is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Bing", age: 44 },
      { name: "name4", is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Chains", age: 27 },
      { name: "name5", is_teacher: true, nick_name: "Jp", age: 58 },
      { name: "name6", is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Unix", age: 50 },
      { name: "name7", is_teacher: false, nick_name: "Grouch", age: 33 },
    ],
  };
  converBool(val) {
    // convert is_Teacher (boolean) and check if true or false and return value
    return val === true ? "yes" : "no";
  }

  render = () => {
    switch (this.state.selected) {
      case 1:
        return this.state.studentArr === 0 ? (
          <p>No Students / Teachers Found!</p>
        ) : (
          <ul>
            <div>
              <p>asdada</p>
            </div>
            {this.state.studentArr.map((student) => (
              <li key={student.name}>
                Name: {student.name} ,Teacher:{" "}
                {this.converBool(student.is_teacher)} , NickName:{" "}
                {student.nick_name} , Age: {student.age}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        );
    case 2: //... 
    }
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ selected: 1 })}>
          Click To See All Teachers
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ selected: 2 })}>
          Click To See All Teachers
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ selected: 3 })}>
          Click To See All Age 50+
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ selected: 4 })}>
          Click To See All Student with Age below 30
        </button>
        {render()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but after i add selected: null,
and write all the cases 
in the web its show me error 

'selected' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Should be this.state.selected, sorry I forgot that part.